# Access Windows network drives inside powershell ssh session

Tags: windows, powershell, openssh

I'm trying to automate executing some scripts on windows remotely from a linux box. The script will read some files on the shared drive, then print out some output.

**Problem**

The script locates in `C:\scripts\script.py` and it will read `R:` (which is mapped from `\\remoteFile`)

Executing the script with `ssh user@windows01 "python C:\scripts\script.py"` results in `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'R:'`

The script works locally, it also works when I modify the path to be a local path, and move the files to the local path

**Expected outcome**

The mapped drive `R:` or the remote path `\\remoteFile` should be accessible inside the ssh session

**Workaround**

Map the drive before my command, i.e.

`ssh user@windows01 "net use R: \\\\remoteFile ${password} /user:user; python C:\scripts\script.py"`

The solution works but not optimal: I have a lot of scripts running at different schedules so it'd mean adding this line to all of the jobs.

**Things I have tried**

- Modify the script to read `\\remoteFile` directly, but that path also doesn't exist inside the ssh session
- I have read the [github issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/issues/139) and set `EnabledLInkedConnections` but the path is still not found inside the ssh session
- I have read [this issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/issues/518) but it doesn't account for ssh sessions with public keys
- credSSP might be an solution, but it requires more setup on both server/client side and I'm not sure if it's worth trying (I heard that credSSP has security issues too)

**Question**

Is there any clean way to read the remote files inside the ssh session? The script execution should be fully automated so any solution that requires interactive command/manaul input are not considered.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why it works, and lets you map the drive locally, is because you have direct access, and permissions to do so. The reason you can't access a share, while on a machine you're remoted into, is because of the good 'ol [kerberos double hop issue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/askds/understanding-kerberos-double-hop). Easiest solution would be to get that file locally on the remote machine, instead of a share. Then run the local file.

Comment: Thanks! Thats means I either stick to current approach(run net use before executing command), or use some sort of sftp to get the file first? There's no standard windows way to solve this?